# Inserting into a database using JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am trying to insert into a database using JDBC and each thread will be inserting into the database. I need to insert around 30-35 columns. I wrote a stored procedure that will UPSERT into those columns.

The problem I am facing is that in the `run()` method, I have around 30 columns written over there for insertion. Is there any way I can simplify my run method so that it doesn't looks so messy which is looking right now for me? And I have a few more columns as well. So if I keep on adding new columns there, it will be looking so messy at one point in my run method.

Is there any way to clean this, keeping in mind the thread safety issues?

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private Connection dbConnection = null;
    private CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

    public Task() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    dbConnection = getDbConnection();
    callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(Constants.UPSERT_SQL);

    callableStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(2, Constants.getaAccount(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(3, Constants.getaAdvertising(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(4, Constants.getaAvgSellingPriceMainCats(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(5, Constants.getaCatAndKeywordRules(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(6, Constants.getaClvBehavior(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(7, Constants.getaClvChurn(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(8, Constants.getaClvInfo(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(9, Constants.getaClvSegmentation(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(10, Constants.getaCsaCategoriesPurchased(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(11, Constants.getaCustomerService(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(12, Constants.getaDemographic(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(13, Constants.getaFinancial(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(14, Constants.getaGeolocation(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(15, Constants.getaInterests(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(16, Constants.getaLastContributorsPurchased(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(17, Constants.getaLastItemsLost(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(18, Constants.getaLastItemsPurchased(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(19, Constants.getaLastProductsPurchased(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(20, Constants.getaLastSellersPurchasedFrom(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(21, Constants.getaMainCategories(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(22, Constants.getaMessaging(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(23, Constants.getaPositiveSellers(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(24, Constants.getaPromo(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(25, Constants.getaScores(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(26, Constants.getaSegmentation(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(27, Constants.getaSellers(userId));
    callableStatement.setString(28, Constants.getaSrpBuyerUpiCount(userId));
    }
  }



    private Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

          Class.forName(Constants.DRIVER_NAME);
      dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

      return dbConnection;
    }
```

Comment: I have the felling that your Constants are not constant.

Comment: Yeah, they are not constants. Before posting here I have renamed the name just to shorten it.

Comment: As callableStatement is an instance field it is not shared and there is no need to synchronize it.

Comment: Thanks mnhg for the suggestion. In general how do we decide when we want to synchronize the method? If you cane explain me then I can understand more. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what the "constant" methods are doing? Are they retrieving a simple value, or calculating some things? Given the only argument is userId it looks like it might be a simple lookup. Is it from a database, or something hard-coded, or previously read in from the database? If there is an explicit table mapping userId to various values you could simplify things by iterating the table to create the callableStatement. Any new additions to the table would automatically be picked up then when creating the statement.

Comment: There's nothing ugly about this code - it's well-written, clear, and straightforward.  You can't make it any better, even by refactoring out all the `setString()`s.

Comment: You might want to look at using a library such as iBatis to do much of the legwork for you. Here's a simple example that demonstrates [calling a stored function with iBatis](http://3rdstage.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-stored-procedure-with-ibatis.html).

Answer (score 4):

**Extract a method.**

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    ... 
    private completeStatement (CallableStatement stmt, Strung userId)
    {
        callableStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(userId));
        ...
    }  

    @Override
    public void run() {
        dbConnection = getDbConnection();
        callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(Constants.UPSERT_SQL);
        completeStatement(callableStatement,userId) 

    }
}

private Connection getDBConnection() {
    ...
}
```

But find a more suitable name for what your statement is doing.

Comment: I was not able to understand what do you mean? Can provide some example so that I can understand better?

Comment: I update the code.

Comment: Thanks mnhg for the suggestion. Now it is more clear. One more doubt I have is, in this case we won't be making `completeStatement ` method `synchronized`?

Comment: There are many discussion on stackoverflow regarding this topic: [start here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840959/how-to-judge-which-object-to-be-synchronized-in-java-thread/9841004#9841004)

Comment: +1 because the first step is to isolate the code in its own method. I think more may be possible, depending what those Constants.xxx() methods are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Some minor notes:

1. `dbConnection` and `callableStatement` might be local variables.
2. If more than one thread calls the `run` method at the same time the shared `dbConnection` and `callableStatement` references might lead to resource leaks/race conditions.
3. I'd consider using [`setString(String parameterName, String x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which uses readable parameter names instead of integer indexes.

Comment: (10k! Whoah! Congrats!)